# allow AOT compatible way to provide custom templateUrl replacement for Angular component

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am looking for an option to build Angular library containing components with possibility to configure them with custom `templateUrl`s. The idea is to customize templates in the library ahead of building an app so I'd like to be able to fully leverage AOT - ideally static. I can imagine some dedicated logic eg. custom decorator to be used in place or along with `@Component` to accomplish my need.

While searching for customization of templates most of the information I've found refer to runtime customization which is not necessary in my case.
I'd appreciate any ideas and suggestions.

After some research I found that what I am looking for is to build a library with

```
"angularCompilerOptions": {
  "enableResourceInlining": false
}
```

yet then templates are not bundled with library at all. Ideally I'd like to have the template resources bundled with library and then inline them while building final app, although I'd be ok to keep them separate.

**UPDATE**: one advice I've found is to relay on ivy and use higher order component - this would great option yet as I am using Ionic support for ivy is still on its way.

**UPDATE 2**: temporary solution/workaround I was able to get working is:
for the component I want to customize use:

```html
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="template">
</ng-container>

<ng-template #default>
  default content template
</ng-template>
```

```js
@Component({
    selector: 'original-component',
    templateUrl: './original-component.html',
    styleUrls: ['original-component.scss'],
})
export class OriginalComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    @ViewChild('default', {read: TemplateRef, static: false}) defaultTemplate: TemplateRef<any>;
    template: TemplateRef<any>;

    constructor(
        @Optional() @Inject(TEMPLATE_OVERRIDE_KEY) public readonly templateOverrideKey: string,
        private templateRegistry: TemplateRegistry) {}

    ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        if (this.templateRegistry.get(this.templateOverrideKey)) {
            this.template = this.templateRegistry.get(this.templateOverrideKey);
        }
        if (!this.template) {
            this.template = this.defaultTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

then in the same way define custom template and use `TemplateRegistry` service to pass this as an override.

downsides of this solution

- this is dynamic option that is performed in runtime and I'd prefer just "replace" the template before build as only one version ot the template will be used in particular application
- I need to explicitly use the custom component somewhere (eg in the app-component) so it will be initialized and only then have access to the `TemplateRef`
- need to use `let-ctx` and access all the original data via `ctx.myVar` as thats how the `ng-template` works right now.

note for voting to close the question - I'd appreciate at least some comment elaborating how this question can be improved or what could be an alternate approach.

Comment: Each ng-template can be its own component. Without knowing more about what you're trying to do or the full mark-up its really hard to really answer.  Either way, you're going to end up with a lot of markup still and you will need to use @Input/@Output to pass data around.

Comment: thanks! I am investigating now an option to swap whole components (and/or possibly decorator/directive to mark swappable components/templates) with `ComponentFactoryResolver` and `ViewContainerRef.createComponent`, will try to share then a stackblitz.
I assume for swapping the template they should share same data interface. So as component may be required anyway I can end up swapping whole components and share same Interface.